# RESTful design carry forward

Tags: rest

This is a good design question more than anything.  I have service that deals data entered after a mission is complete.  The next log in the sequence will start with the ending total equipment time of the last log and the log serial number will increment by 1.  Is it a good design to have GET create a new log if one doesn't exist and return that?  Or is it better to have POST create the new log from the old with an empty post and return a 201 with a re-direct?  I don't see a scenario where input on the new log will be meaningful without having the carry forward data present from the previous log.  I can see doing it either way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976050/restful-way-of-getting-a-resource-but-creating-it-if-it-doesnt-exist-yet

Comment: I think that answers my question. I appreciate the link.