# How to handled (and supress) normal servicestack errors

Tags: servicestack

I have servicestack class with a method that may take a while to return.  Most of the time it returns within 60 seconds, but sometimes it does not.   The JsonServiceClient that calls this service has a 60 second timeout.

Since the client times out, it aborts the request.  Everything is as expected.

However, the service method that was called eventually returns - let's say it takes 75 seconds total.  So, 15 seconds after the client aborted the connection, it finishes.

This kicks of a bunch of errors in the service.  The errors I get are:

Remote host closed connection - yep, it sure did.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80070040): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070040.
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse httpRes, IHttpRequest httpReq, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

That is followed by am error where servicestack fails to write the response.  Of course, this should fail, but should it have even tried to send this - as the connection is closed?

```
INFO  ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions [(null)] - Failed to write error to response: {0}
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.
at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteErrorToResponse(IHttpResponse httpRes, IHttpRequest httpReq, String contentType, String operationName, String errorMessage, Exception ex, Int32 statusCode)
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
```

I have logging setup and it logs these errors anytime a client disconnects in the middle of a service operation.  The errors generated all come from this [class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.cs).  I have tried to turn logging off for this namespace with this, but it does not work:

```
<logger name="ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal">
  <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

So, two questions.

1)  Why does SS try to send the error to a closed response (2nd exception)

2)  How do I stop these from being logged?

(Just to be clear, I love servicestack and everything is working quite nicely.  I just want to be able to only be notified of real issues only)

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question but why not simply return something like a [202](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079367/use-http-status-202-for-asynchronous-operations) response and fire off your long running process asynchronously with something like [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx)?

Comment: Mike, most of the time this returns within seconds - so it is not a big deal.  I just want to be able to stop these exceptions from being something we see or care about.  Thanks.