# Why can't I delete native events with Cronofy.com?

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api, cronofy

I am using Cronofy to integrate my application (only locally tested yet) with multiple calendar platforms.

I am having trouble getting it to update or delete events which are created natively (google or outlook) and I cannot understand why. The documentation (https://www.cronofy.com/developers/api/) is not sufficing to understand it and there's not much more out there besides that.

When I send a request for deletion of a native event I do get a 202 HTTP response back but the event remains in my google/outlook calendar and if I do the same for my own event it deletes there smoothly with the same 202.

How can I make it work? I've read about auth flow and that 202 means it is processing but this processingtime seems to be taking too long for it to be that (~2days)

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), **202 HTTP response** means that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this. Check this [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079367/use-http-status-202-for-asynchronous-operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As standard, we sandbox calendar access and don't allow developers to edit existing events in end-users calendars.

There is a process you can go through to request extended permissions on one or more of a user's calendars if you need this functionality. Let me know via the support@cronofy.com if you would like access to this.

We differentiate between 'managed' and 'unmanaged' events in our API to help streamline the kinds of operations different use cases require.

Managed events are events that are created by your application. When they are created we require an `event_id` which is your id for the event in your application. You have complete control over events with an `event_id`. In order to delete a managed event you would pass the `event_id` as the identifying parameter https://www.cronofy.com/developers/api/#delete-event

Unmanaged events are events created by the user in their calendar. These have an `event_uid` which is used to identify the event. If you have sufficient permission to delete unmanaged events then you would pass this `event_uid` as the identifying parameter.

The reason we're returning a **202** is that our API is asynchronous. Every API request is a journal operation which is executed by a worker. We don't inline calls to downstream APIs. Instead we protect your application performance from having to deal with whether a calendar server is available and responsive to meet your request.

I hope this helps explain what you're seeing. Any questions, let me know either hear or at support@cronofy.com.

Adam